# Run CSV Column Through Webform via Python

Tags: python, excel, csv, mechanize

I've made and deleted a couple of threads on here in reference to a single issue I'm having, only because I haven't been able to accurately describe what I'm trying to do.

Essentially: I want to automate a search process. This would involve automatically selecting a radio button on [this webpage](http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/Content/Search/iapd_Search.aspx), then feeding each cell of column B:B in [this excel spreadsheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vv7pq48vgnhtuex/Legal%20Names.xlsx?dl=0) into one of the forms enabled by the radio button. Ideally, the process would also populate the spreadsheet (or a new .csv or .txt file) with the output from each search.

I am utterly at a loss as to how to integrate excel with Python. I have the following script so far:

```
import mechanize
URL = 'http://www.adviserinfo.sec.gov/IAPD/Content/Search/iapd_Search.aspx'
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(URL)
for form in br.forms():
   print "Form name:", form.name
   print form

form.set_all_readonly(False)
```

But from there I don't know what to do. I'm not a programmer; teaching myself Python for this project. Any and all help will keep me from manually copying and pasting 1,175 names into a search bar, which is neither a good use of my time nor an opportunity to learn anything new. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to see a Excel file in txt (open it with notepad or anything you like).  That is the "real" archive, the divisions, pretty much like html.

For each row you want to write on excel, instead of print "Form name:", form.name you'll have to write on a file something like "form.name".

Do not forget to create the archive before the printing.  Note that you'll create a xls file, and write him as you saw in the txt.